# do we need a Mac device to create ipa file from windows machine?

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, ipa

Do we need a mac device to create ipa file and install right away to iPhone device just like for android apk?

Thank you,

Comment: Yes, you need a Mac.

Comment: yes, you need a Mac device with Updated XCode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, we still need a mac to generate the ipa file .

Because before the step we need to select the **provisioning profile** , which is only accessible once connecting to mac.

Refer to [Creating an IPA from visual Studio for windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/deploy-test/app-distribution/ipa-support?tabs=windows#creating-an-ipa).